# Saving an elasticsearch query for reuse possible?

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

Does anyone know if this is possible? The closest thing I've seen is the [save query option in Kibana](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/save-load-delete-query.html). But I'd like to have this for Java/Spring. My idea is for users to build their own elasticsearch queries (works!) and I want to add the option to be able to save them for reuse. Does Elasticsearch or a library for Java/Spring support this function? I'm aware of search templates but it seems better for searchbar inputs and not something where a user can 'build' possibly complicated queries at will.

My last-resort-dumb-idea is to just save the entire query DSL as string or json somewhere and just send it again.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the query in a elasticsearch index by using the field type `percolator`
your index `mapping` should be somethings like this

```
{
"mappings": {
"properties": {
"query": { #A
"type": "percolator" #B
},
"tags": { #D
"type": "text"
}
}
}
}
```

Comment: I was under the impression that percolators are not ideal for (possibly) complex queries. Is that incorrect?

Comment: I don't think so if the type is designed to store ES queries I think it can handle the complex ones